# Missing overscroll in Lollipop with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

When using Cordova to display web pages, I'm not getting any overscroll effect in android 5. Android 4.+ seems to display the overscroll glow just fine.

I've tried it with both  OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS and OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS, but nothing seems to work on Lollipop.

Looking for a solution or even ideas on how to debug this. 
Thanks!